# openssl_verify does not have OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256 definition in openssl.php in eclipse php project

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, openssl, php-openssl

I am trying to use openssl_verify with OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256 in a php project using eclipse PDT. But I am not able to verify as OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256 is not defined in openssl.php file in Core API. I create project by specifying PHP 5.4 as it is mentioned in [PHP Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/openssl.signature-algos.php)
that this flag was added in PHP 5.4.8. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.
Can anybody tell me how to get this working?

Thanks

Comment: I have just created pull request for this issue at github.com/eclipse/pdt/pull/17 .
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try string:

```
"sha256WithRSAEncryption"
```

instead of the constant:

```
OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256
```

([Source](http://php.net/manual/zh/function.openssl-verify.php))

Answer (score -1):

Open Core.php under Core API. You can see

> // Start of Core v.5.4.0RC6

This means that files under Core API were built based on PHP "v.5.4.0RC6".

You need to define newer elements by yourself.

([Here](https://github.com/atlanto/php_language_library/blob/master/pdt_tools.php.core.nl1.utf-8/nl/ja/Resources/language/php5.4/openssl.php) is an example *in Japanese*. I'm sorry but I don't know whether the English version exists. The latest original is [here](http://git.eclipse.org/c/pdt/org.eclipse.pdt.git/tree/plugins/org.eclipse.php.core/Resources/language/php5.4/openssl.php).)